# Why are my TensorFlow network weights and costs NaN when I use RELU activations?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nan

I can't get TensorFlow RELU activations (neither `tf.nn.relu` nor `tf.nn.relu6`) working without NaN values for activations and weights killing my training runs.

I believe I'm following all the right general advice. For example I initialize my weights with

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(w_dims, stddev=0.1))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1 if neuron_fn in [tf.nn.relu, tf.nn.relu6] else 0.0, shape=b_dims))
```

and use a slow training rate, e.g.,

```
tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.02, momentum=0.5).minimize(cross_entropy_loss)
```

But any network of appreciable depth results in `NaN` for cost and and at least some weights (at least in the summary histograms for them). In fact, the cost is often `NaN` right from the start (before training).

I seem to have these issues even when I use L2 (about 0.001) regularization, and dropout (about 50%).

Is there some parameter or setting that I should adjust to avoid these issues? I'm at a loss as to where to even begin looking, so any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: there is nothing magical about relu. Error is in your code, thus you should provide it. Why do you initialize bias to 0.1 instaed of 0? Why not simply tf.Variable + tf.zeros ?

Comment: @lejlot: The idea for 0.1 comes [from Google](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#weight-initialization).

Comment: How many layers are there in your network? It seems like a gradient explosion problem.

Comment: @LifuHuang: The problem seems to appear with >4. But even when I can avoid my NaN issue, RELUs don't actually seem to work that well.

Comment: @lejlot: Actually, the problem vanishes if I simply change stddev=0.1 to stddev=0.01. But as you say (and despite quite a bit of what I've read) RELU is not magical. In fact, training is no faster and much more erratic. I'm not sure why there's so much hype about them. Is there a general set of changes I nee to make to a successful model with sigmoid activations to get it working with RELUs? Clearly (or at least it seems from my experience here) making sure all my weights are ["slightly positive"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#weight-initialization).

Comment: the "hype" is about many things. In particular for actually deep networks (lets say of at least 10-20 hidden layers), relu behave way better than sigmoids. They converge faster and to better solutions, they are easier to implement (and faster to compute, which is important if you put this on gpus). There are some new, specific heuristics for initialization which are well suited for relus (and different from old sigmoid-based ones), which you can find in nips papers.

Comment: @lejlot: Can you point me to particular NIPS papers on RELU initialization?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf

Comment: @lejlot: So something like `stddev=np.sqrt(2 / np.prod(input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[1:]))`

Comment: @lejlot: If that's right (and it does seem to work much better, though I still get occasional explosions), I'd take it (your article link and some TF code illustrating an implementation) as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following [He *et. al*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf) (as suggested in [lejlot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658050/lejlot)'s comment), initializing the weights of the *l*-th layer to a zero-mean Gaussian distribution with standard deviation

[image]

where *n<sub>l</sub>* is the flattened length of the the input vector or

```
stddev=np.sqrt(2 / np.prod(input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[1:]))
```

results in weights that generally do not diverge.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a softmax classifier at the top of your network, try to make the initial weights of the layer just below the softmax very small (e.g. std=1e-4). This makes the initial distribution of outputs of the network very soft (high temperature), and helps ensure that the first few steps of your optimization are not too large and numerically unstable.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [gradient clipping](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#processing-gradients-before-applying-them) and/or a smaller learning rate?

Basically, you will need to process your gradients before applying them, as follows (from tf docs, mostly):

```
# Replace this with what follows
# opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.02, momentum=0.5).minimize(cross_entropy_loss)

# Create an optimizer.
opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.5)

# Compute the gradients for a list of variables.
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(cross_entropy_loss, tf.trainable_variables())

# grads_and_vars is a list of tuples (gradient, variable).  Do whatever you
# need to the 'gradient' part, for example cap them, etc.
capped_grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(gv[0], -5., 5.), gv[1]) for gv in grads_and_vars]

# Ask the optimizer to apply the capped gradients.
opt = opt.apply_gradients(capped_grads_and_vars)
```

Also, [the discussion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498127) might help.