# Is there a way to clip intermediate exploded gradients in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, clipping, gradient, adam

Problem: a very long RNN net

```
N1 -- N2 -- ... --- N100
```

For a Optimizer like `AdamOptimizer`, the `compute_gradient()` will give gradients to all training variables.

However, it might explode during some step.

A method like in [how-to-effectively-apply-gradient-clipping-in-tensor-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498127/how-to-effectively-apply-gradient-clipping-in-tensor-flow/36501922#36501922) 
can clip large final gradient.

But how to clip those intermediate ones?

One way might be manually do the backprop from "N100 --> N99", clip the gradients, then "N99 --> N98" and so on, but that's just too complicated.

So my question is: Is there any easier method to clip the intermediate gradients? (of course, strictly speaking, they are not gradients anymore in the mathematical sense)

Comment: Rough idea -- wrap each of your layers into a py_func that uses custom gradient as done [here](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342). The custom gradient function would take vector of backward values and return the clipped version.

Comment: clipping weights and/or activations might also help to prevent large gradients

Answer (score 2):

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def gradient_clipping(x):
  return x, lambda dy: tf.clip_by_norm(dy, 10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `custom_gradient` decorator to make a version of `tf.identity` which clips intermediate exploded gradients.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe

@tfe.custom_gradient
def gradient_clipping_identity(tensor, max_norm):
  result = tf.identity(tensor)

def grad(dresult):
    return tf.clip_by_norm(dresult, max_norm), None

return result, grad
```

Then use `gradient_clipping_identity` as you'd normally use identity and your gradients will be clipped in the backward pass.