# How to clip the gradient norm on the grad_and_var tuple in tensorflow-r1.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

After getting the `grad_and_var` tuple with `compute_gradient`:

```
opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate)
grad_and_var = opt.compute_gradients(losses, params)
```

I'd like to clip the `grad_and_var`. But when I do:

```
clipped_gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grad_and_var, max_gradient_norm)
```

directly, the resulting `clipped_gradients` is a list of tensor, that means, the gradient and the variables has been concatenated.

If I do

```
clipped_gradients = [tf.clip_by_global_norm(x[0], max_gradient_norm)[0] for x in grad_and_var]
```

I got such an error:

```
TypeError: t_list should be a sequence
```

Do you have any idea that how can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach that I have seen is to zip `clipped_gradients` and your variables and to use `opt.apply_gradients` on the zipped list, like in the code below (taken from [here](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py), lines 78-83):

```
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars),
                args.grad_clip)
with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr)
self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can clip norm and add gradient noise like this:

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.config.learning_rate)
gvs = opt.compute_gradients(self.loss)
gvs = [(tf.clip_by_norm(grad,self.config.max_grad), val) for grad,val in gvs]
gvs = [(tf.add(grad, tf.random_normal(tf.shape(grad),stddev=self.config.grad_noise)), val) for grad,val in gvs]
self.train_op = opt.apply_gradients(gvs)
```

Comment: It should at least be pointed out that this is not clipping by the global norm.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43486487/1084865.